# mariaDB uses the wrong disk

Tags: mariadb, innodb

I am using mariaDB version 10.2 - innodb, with a boot and ssd drive.
the boot drive is only for root, all the data is configured to be on the ssd and mysql dir is mounted on to is.
when writing I see that the data is being written to the ssd.
when running a big update query i can see the that the ssd is working but after the memory is getting full it starts to use the root disk and causing an IOWAIT which results in a restart.
swap is disabled.
could someone share an advice on how solving this problem?

Comment: Give it enough memory, or do smaller updates.

Comment: How big are the drives?  Where is MariaDB installed?  Where is `tmpdir`?  How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: This probably belongs in dba.stackexchange.com .